# How to show warning when robocopy is overwriting a file?

Tags: powershell, dll, version, robocopy, compareto

currently I need to use powershell and Robocopy to copy from a source directory to target directory. It is a library files consists a lots of .dll.

I will need to overwrite the .dll that exist in target directory. However, some of the .dll in target directory are newer version. Therefore, before overwriting, i will need to prompt a warning to tell users about that. So that they are aware of that. How can i check and compare the version/properties of the .dlls before doing the robocopy?

I have checked that there is no such switch for robocopy.

Any solution for this ? Thank you

Comment: See if you can [check the DLL version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005) first. If this works, just tell Robocopy to ignore said file.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, currently i am passing all the child items for both directories as an array. Do you know what is the fastest way to compare in this way? thanks again