# Find specific .exe files on a computer with PowerShell

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, monitoring

So at the company I am currently doing my internship at, they have about 20 'technical laptops' that have company-specified software. They are located in the C:\ directory.

For example:

`aaa.exe` is located at `C:\aaa\aaa.exe`

`bbb.exe` is located at `C:\bbb\bbb.exe`

What I actually need is a .ps1 script to show these specific executables in a list.

What I have so far is:
`Get-ChildItem C:\ -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".exe"}`

Now, I believe it's just edit the search query because this gives me all the .exe files on the C:\ drive and I just need **aaa** and **bbb**.

FYI: I need the script so that I can use it to monitor zabbix agents and see if the specific software is on the computer so I can run this script on the Zabbix Server.

Comment: Do you also need the path to these executables?

Comment: The path is already shown with the command that I use to filter and find only .exe files

Output for example:

Directory: C:\aaa

Mode          LastWriteTime          Length   Name
-a----           21/05/2012   9:54     99999    aaa.exe

I just want the output to only show aaa and bbb and not everything on the C:\ drive

Comment: You can improve the filter to add specific files you are looking for or you can use `-include` parameter. The former is a long way, the latter being a short one. Something like this - `gci C:\ -recurse -include 'aaa.exe', 'bbb.exe'`. Is that what you want?

Comment: It's definitely a big helper thanks! I just noticed that these technical laptops don't have a nice structure when it comes down to having software in the same directory. How would I apply this to search not only on the C:\ drive but also on the D:\ drive? I'm sorry. I'm not too familiar with queries

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for the `-include` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -recurse -include "aaa.exe", "bbb.exe"
```

Comment: This is definitely something I was looking for! You're the man!

Answer (score 1):

@Martin Brandl has already answered your first question. For the second part of your question, you can do something like this -

```
$AllDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
foreach ($drive in $AllDrives)
{
    Get-ChildItem -path $drive.Root -recurse -include "aaa.exe", "bbb.exe"
}
```

Or you can do it in one line -

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' | % {Get-ChildItem -path $_.Root -recurse -include "aaa.exe", "bbb.exe"}
```

You can change the `-PSProvider` parameter if your executables are on other drives other than `FileSystem` drives.

Comment: Is there also a way to find the version of the executable ?

Comment: `[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("somefilepath").FileVersion`
Check [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/12/07/how-to-correctly-check-file-versions-with-powershell/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686/get-file-version-in-powershell)

Comment: **Thanks a lot !**