# Search and Set ProductVersion from a .dll file

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, file, dll

Hello Stackoverflow community that rocks the Dev/IT world,

**What do I want to accomplish?**

Via PowerShell perform a search of a specific `.dll` file and from it extract the `ProductVersion` which will allow identifying if the software release is an `-RC` and not a final version `non -RC` and afterwards use that `ProductVersion` to other postprocessing activities,

**What values can I see when do open the *.dll* file with VisualStudio**?

There are two columns, **Key** and **value** and below of it the series of available *Versions* and *Descriptons*:

- FILEVERSION: 1,1,0,0
- PRODUCTVERSION: 1,1,0,0
- FILELAGSMASK: 0x3fl
- FILEFLAGS: 0x0L
- FILEOS: 0x4L
- FILETYPE: 0x4L
- Assembly Version: 1,1,0,0
- FILEVERSION: 1,1,0,0
- **ProductVersion**: 1,1,0,0-**RC2** -->this is the type of version we require to find and afterward set

Comment: Look at `FileInfo` members.

Comment: Hello @zett42 tanks for taking the time to reply, please take a look at the new lines did add to the body of this publication, the field that normally I do require to search the *RC* notation is located at *ProductVersion*, do you know which PowerShell command syntax could I use to fin this value within this field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get file version in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686/get-file-version-in-powershell)

Comment: Linked question has answers how to _get_ `ProductVersion` field. I don't know how to _set_ it though. If you can't find an answer, it would be better to ask a separate question.

Comment: The guide of @zett42 combined with a Regex search did allow me to accomplish this implementation, so thanks so much