# PowerShell - Read file version from all files in zip

Tags: powershell

I need to read all file version for each dll and exe files that located inside a zip.
This is what I have so far. I was able to hold a dll but there is no .fileversion for the object

```
$vips = Get-ChildItem -path C:\_Projects\temp\Patch_1296247.vip
$checkfiles= "*.dll"
#C:\_Projects\temp\Patch_1296247.vip

foreach ($file in $vips) {
    try {
        $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($file, "Read")
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
        continue
    }
    $dlls = $zip.Entries.Where({ $_.Name -like "*.dll" })
    foreach($dll in $dlls) {

    $dll.FileVersion
    $zip.Dispose()}}
```

The dll have only those properties

[image]

If I run this line I can get the dll version.Maybe because it is not in a ZIP? How can I add it to my script?

```
(Get-Item C:\_Projects\temp\Patch_1296247\ADWalk_4.0.0.101\JobAdWalk\AdWalk\a.Client.ServicesProvider.dll).VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

Its ok to write the if like that? I want to print all dlls with 1.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0
I get that all dlls is ok although all of them with 1.0.0.0 or 0.0.0.0
(($dll.VersionInfo) -eq "1.0.0.0") --> False ?!?!

Maybe it should be like this?

```
if ((($dll.VersionInfo) -eq "1.0.0.0") -or (($dll.VersionInfo) -eq"0.0.0.0")
```

Or should be:

```
if (($dll.VersionInfo) -eq "1.0.0.0")
{}
elseif (($dll.VersionInfo) -eq "0.0.0.0")
{}



foreach ($file in $vips) {
    try {
        $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($file, $tempFolder)
        $dlls = Get-ChildItem $tempFolder -Include "*.dll","*.exe" -Recurse
        foreach($dll in $dlls) {
            #$dll.VersionInfo
        if (($dll.VersionInfo) -eq "1.0.0.0" -or "0.0.0.0")
        {
            write-host
            Write-host "The version of $($dll.Name) is wrong!!!" -ForegroundColor Red
          
        }
        else {write-host "All dlls are ok"}
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not aware of a file system that stores metadata like "fileversion". So maybe you need a tool to read such metadata especially from DLL files.

Comment: You have to temporarily extract the file to [get the file version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30686/7571258). Theoretically you could do it without temp file by parsing it from the stream of the ZIP entry in-memory, if you find an external library for this.

Comment: Sounds great but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$dll` in your example has `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry` type. This type doesn't have `VersionInfo` property. This property is member of `System.IO.FileInfo` type. Thus, you need firstly to convert the zipped file into the `System.IO.FileInfo` type and then you can read your property.

You can do it for example by extracting the archive to temporary directory and then clean-up:

```
$vips = Get-ChildItem -path C:\_Projects\temp\Patch_1296247.vip
$checkfiles= "*.dll"
$tempFolder = "c:\temp\tempzip"

foreach ($file in $vips) {
    try {
        $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($file, $tempFolder)
        $dlls = Get-ChildItem $tempFolder "*.dll" 
        foreach($dll in $dlls) {
            $dll.VersionInfo
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
        continue
    }
    finally {
        Remove-Item $tempFolder -Force -Recurse
    }    
}
```

Comment: Nice! The code could be slightly improved by not hard-coding the temp directory, e. g. `$tempFolder = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) (New-GUID).ToString('n')`

Comment: What the ('n') do?

Comment: This line is opening many folders in temp without deletion 
$tempFolder = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) (New-GUID).ToString('n')